# Spring 3 Security - what are and how exactly do the subtags under `<http>` work?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am learning Spring 3 Security using an amazing book called Spring in Practice. I have questions regarding how exactly the tags under the `<http>` tag work behind the scenes.

In the book it says:

> the `<http>` element works by creating a chain of servlet filters to handle
>   different aspects of web security. By setting `auto-config="true"`, you
>   enable the filters for form-based logins, HTTP basic authentication,
>   and logouts. If you prefer, you can set `auto-config="false"` (that's
>   the default) and specify the desired filters manually.

I have 3 questions regarding Spring 3 Security.

1). Is each element under `<http>` such as `<form-login>` and `<remember-me>` a filter that gets created? How does `<http>` element create the filters?

2). If I was to  set `auto-config="false"`, how would I go about specifying the desired filters manually?

3). As I understand, the `<authentication-manager>` tag represents the `AuthenticationManager` interface. But how does a tag do this? There is no bean in the xml called AuthenticationManager.. Same goes for the nested tag `<authentication-provider>`. The AuthenticationProvider bean is not listed in the Spring xml anywhere...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The http element and the authentication-manager element are part of the spring security namespace configuration.

These elements allow to declare what is the end-result that we want from a security point of view (use a form login, this is the logout page, etc.), instead of declaring spring beans and wiring them together.

The end-result is a more declarative, readable and maintainable way of configuring security, as opposed to wiring the beans together and building the filter chain by hand. Also with these elements there is usually less configuration because defaults are applied.

These elements are an example of a security XML based [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). The way that it works at runtime is like this:

Spring will read all the elements of the http and authentication-manager into memory using XML libraries such as a DOM implementation.

Depending on the contents of the XML a chain of filters will be built in the case of the http element, check class [AuthenticationConfigBuilder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/http/AuthenticationConfigBuilder.java) to see how it's built.

Using this to go over the different questions raised:

1. Not necessarily, each element does not have to be a filter. Spring can parse the config to do basically anything and not necessarily always create a filter. An element in the config namespace might for example correspond to a component used by one of the filters.
2. The http element section of this [pdf](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.pdf) has several examples
3. This is done similarly to the http element in [AuthenticationManagerBeanDefinitionParser](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/authentication/AuthenticationManagerBeanDefinitionParser.java)

Comment: I do feel the OP's pain though. Spring Security really really needs Java config and I don't think Spring Security has that option. Unlike plain old `<bean>` config, spring security especially difficult to figure out and I almost always have to go look at the code.

Comment: I would much rather prefer the explicit `<bean> / <property>` wiring so that I know what is going on behind the scenes. Everything seems so abstracted away and using the security namespace adds the complexity to the configuration.

Comment: I believe that using the namespace is optional and we can always wire things ourselves in case of more advanced uses. I am not sure if for a very advanced use case it's not better just to wire everything, as we don't use the defaults anymore. Also for reducing the pain of XML based DSL's having a look at the XSD of the namespace helps to see what the possibilities are  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd , specially the description tags. But i think I see what you mean, it hides the internals that you need to understand what is really going on.

Comment: @AdamGent Spring Security 3.2 added Java Configuration support (to be GA later this month). See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#jc